# How to make HTTPS request using HttpClient in dart?

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm using HttpClient from dart (dart:io package, NOT dart:http) and I'd like to send an HTTPS request. Is there a way to do that? I can't seem to find a method that would allow me that.

Comment: why not try `HttpClient.open(url)`?

Comment: I don't see a method with that signature....

Comment: Sorry, didn't even see the methods with openUrl. I was expecting to be able to pass in scheme to open. The other methods were not suitable as I need other HTTP verbs too (i.e. PUT and PATCH).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dart
new HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('https://www.somedomain.com'));
```

Comment: And, did it work? I think in this case you should just delete the question.

Comment: No, because there is no method with the signature that would allow me to specify url in this form.

Comment: Sorry, there was a method, which I didn't see. I was too much focused around how to pass scheme into open method. There's another method called openUrl which does the job. Nevertheless, it's weird that you can't pass scheme into open method.

Comment: Can you self-answer this with the `openUrl` answer so future Darters can see it?

Comment: Sorry didn't know that the API is so different than in the browser (didn't use it for a while). Now I understand why it was not so obvious.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it didn't work on https, i got this error 
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate(handshake.cc:354))

Comment: @MohamedDernoun https://medium.com/@reme.lehane/flutter-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-development-c3fe2d104acf should help

Answer (score 0):

The steps of sending HTTPS request is the same as HTTP in dart/flutter, one thing you have to add is to allow self signed certificates to handle badCertificateCallback, add this to your HttpClient:

```
var httpClient = HttpClient();
      httpClient.badCertificateCallback =
          ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) =>
              true); // Allow self signed certificates
```

Ref: https://medium.com/@reme.lehane/flutter-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-development-c3fe2d104acf

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/"))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      // Optionally set up headers...
      // Optionally write to the request object...
      // Then call close.
      ...
      return request.close();
    })
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      // Process the response.
      ...
    });
```

Reft: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html

Comment: To add to what Ihda answered,  you can also use this same function and add headers and a body as needed,  you can also use the post method to post with the same format